# Referencing a sheet in a different document is not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was using this formula to pull data from a sheet in the same document and it was working fine:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("1LO97xUQXHScmqzJOOKwZHx-n_FuwhD6GgkoFUciHpMk", "AMB-44-L2-csv!L7"),"\*$|RECYCLE.BIN|System Volume Information|^$"),,REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTRANGE("1LO97xUQXHScmqzJOOKwZHx-n_FuwhD6GgkoFUciHpMk", "AMB-44-L2-csv!L7"),".*\\","   └─   "))
```

Then I decided to pull the same data from a copy of that same sheet, but in another document and now I'm stuck on this:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("1LO97xUQXHScmqzJOOKwZHx-n_FuwhD6GgkoFUciHpMk", ADDRESS(row()-2,column()-1,,,"AMB-44-L2-csv")),"\*$|RECYCLE.BIN|System Volume Information|^$"),,REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTRANGE("1LO97xUQXHScmqzJOOKwZHx-n_FuwhD6GgkoFUciHpMk", ADDRESS(row()-2,column()-1,,,"AMB-44-L2-csv")),".*\\","   └─   "))
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("1LO97xUQXHScmqzJOOKwZHx-n_FuwhD6GgkoFUciHpMk", 
 ADDRESS(ROW()-2,COLUMN()-1,4,1,"AMB-44-L2-csv")),"\*$|RECYCLE.BIN|System Volume Information|^$"),,
 REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTRANGE("1LO97xUQXHScmqzJOOKwZHx-n_FuwhD6GgkoFUciHpMk", 
 ADDRESS(ROW()-2,COLUMN()-1,4,1,"AMB-44-L2-csv")),".*\\","   └─   "))
```

#### note: formula cant be used in column A and row 1 & 2

[image]

Comment: Thanks, player0. You made me realized I was referencing the wrong cell.